# Не отображается в schema символ выбора цвета, как в settings.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

На изображении есть символ выбора цвета:

[image: Есть символ выбора цвета]

Этот код написан в settings.json по умолчанию программы.

А на этом нет такого символа:

[image]

Здесь пытался писать через schema, так как settings.json применяет изменения ко всем следующим документам. А мне надо для одного изменения изменить оформление синтаксиса. Но в schema не ставиться символ выбора цвета, его вообще там нет. Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы в schema появился символ выбора цвета, как на рисунке 1?

Comment: Можно самому настроить с помощью изменения схемы JSON https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_json-schemas-and-settings

Comment: Скажите как это сделать, я только осваиваю vs code и плохо что понимаю.Хотя я пробовал через schema, но почему то не появился этот значок выбора цвета.

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)

Comment: Как минимум, во втором случае у вас json некорректный, возможно vscode не может его распарсить и добавить этот цветной квадратик.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смысл в том, что надо писать через vscode.

Comment: Стоит продублировать текстом.